# How to execute scp command from docker container to outside

Tags: python, docker, networking, docker-compose

my problem is to execute a simple python script running via docker to copy a file from my python script into a server.

I have an rsa private key and if I use it with the bash command it works:

```
scp -i id_rsa my_file username@external_ip:/tmp
```

In my python file I have this code:

```
print("Start scp ....")
success = os.system("scp -i id_rsa my_file username@external_ip:/tmp/")

if success != 0:
    print("scp failed.")
else:
    print("scp success.")
```

If I run my python script from IDE all it's OK, but if I run my python script using docker-compose.yaml file I have this error:

```
python-scp    | Start scp ....
python-scp    | Host key verification failed.
python-scp    | lost connection
python-scp    | scp failed.
python-scp exited with code 0
```

This is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  python-scp:
    container_name: python-scp
    image: python-scp:latest
    networks:
      - my-bridge

networks:
  my-bridge:
    external: true
    name: my-bridge
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Small point... avoid using `os.system`. Use `subprocess` instead https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?#subprocess-replacements

Comment: `I have an rsa private key and if I use it with the bash command it works:` are you running this command from within a docker container?

Comment: This ssh path is especially complex, and involves injecting several different credentials into multiple places.  Might it be more straightforward to restructure your Python application to publish data via an HTTP service, where it can be retrieved from the host without needing any of these credentials?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an explicit error message: `Host key verification failed.`. That means that `ssh` in your container doesn't trust the host key presented by the remote host. This is expected behavior; you would see the same thing running `ssh` from the command line when attempting to connect to a host for the first time.

There are a few possible solutions:

1. You can inject the expected host key into the container. For example, you can mount your `known_hosts` file at an appropriate location inside the container.
2. You can configure  `ssh` in the container to automatically trust unknown host keys by setting the `StrictHostkeycChecking` configuration option to `no`.
3. You can use a tool like [`ssh-keyscan`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keyscan.1) to discover the host key at runtime (from a security perspective this is largely the same as the previous option).